# How to add multiple rows of buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, button, filtering

I am creating an app that would have many categories at the top for filtering (as in I would have items with tags, and I would want to filter items by their tags). Originally I was using scope buttons but that is not user-friendly/visually appealing for many categories. Do you have any suggestions, advice, or existing projects that use a different UI? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scroll view horizontally to show your cat1, cat2, cat3, etc...

main view -> scroll view -> buttons for cat1, cat2, etc....

You can add buttons at run time and set a action.

There are many open source horizontal category bars are available, please search on Google.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) is probably the way to go.  You can have lots of customization in the presentation, including size and flow.  For tagging you could have a custom UIView that renders as a tag and exists within the Collection.

Often people use them for image collections, but you can collect most anything that can be rendered as a `UIView` subclass.